# Prevent Kendo grid popup edit from closing on Error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to handle the server error when creating/updating/deleting item from kendo grid. But when a error is thrown, the kendo grid closes no matter what.

```
  function kendo_error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
                showErrorMessages(key, message);
            });   
          //this does not work
          var grid = this;
          gird.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
          });
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have any other solution? `e.preventDefault()` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Just in case anybody needs this.

```
function kendo_error_handler(gridName) {
        return function (e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var grid = $('#'+gridName).data("kendoGrid");
                grid.one("dataBinding", function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var message = "Errors:\n";
                    $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                        if ('errors' in value) {
                            $.each(value.errors, function () {
                                message += this + "\n";
                            });
                        }
                        showErrorMessages(key, message);
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#errorContainer").text("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

is it cause it says " gird.one(" instead of "grid.one("

Comment: I think it's that plus that the original had `var grid = this;` which changed to `var grid = $('#'+gridName).data("kendoGrid");` in the second. Otherwise, all that changed was that the old error message setup moved into the dataBinding function.